# how to combine setTimeout with curentTime play?

Tags: javascript

I want an audio to be played 14 seconds after the page loaded, and I want the audio to skip the first 2 seconds.
This is my code. Only one of the two codes works at a time.

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('video').play()}, 14000);

var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function () {
this.currentTime=2;
this.play()
});
```

Comment: Which 1 of the two codes works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `play` should occur only in the `setTimeout` handler. Also adjusted the event to `loadedmetadata`:

```
document
    .getElementById('video')
    .addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
        this.currentTime = 2;
    });

setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('video').play()
}, 14000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var position = 2, duration = 14;

document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('canplaythrough', function () {

  this.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {

    if (this.currentTime >= position + duration) {
      this.pause();
    }

  });

  this.currentTime = position;
  this.play();

});
```